# Rate of Magnetic Field Change Per Time

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

I am having issues with the following physics practice problem related to magnetic field change per time.

Given the following circuit and magnetic field, assuming the loop has a radius of 10 cm and an EMF of 10V is measured, what is the rate of field changed per time?

[image]

Using Faraday's law we have:
$$\epsilon = -\frac{\Delta\Phi}{\Delta t} $$
where:
$$\Phi = BA$$

I feel like in order to solve this problem I still need another variable, like "B = 2T", or a time variable, or something. It just doesn't seem like enough information, and I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are heading in the right direction. Area of the loop is given by $\pi r^2$. Since the area enclosed
Is same the only thing changing is magnetic field .

According to your question $\Delta \phi= (\Delta B )A$

Now just substitute this in your equation 1.

Also note that 10v is just the magnitude of the induced emf